# Issue with grid-template-rows

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, grid, tailwind-css

The last row()is not being displayed. Am I missing something?

```
    <div className="grid grid-cols-[70%_30%] grid-rows-[max-content_auto_max-content]
                gap-x-4 w-screen h-screen">

      <div className=' bg-orange-300 col-[1_/_3] row-[1_/_2] max-h-[100px] pr-4'>
        <Navbar />
      </div>

        {/* MAIN BODY */}
      <div className=' bg-slate-500 col-[1_/_2] row-[2_/_3]'> 
          <div className='min-h-full w-full ml-4
                          grid grid-rows-[70%_30%]'>
                <div className='font-studio text-[28px] font-extrabold text-center'>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos tempore voluptatibus non odit fuga itaque, quisquam magnam repellendus reprehenderit asperiores rerum magni, ea, pariatur eligendi expedita iste soluta repudiandae aliquam.
                </div>
                <div className=''>
                    <div className='w-full h-[2px] bg-[#242b2d] skew-y-[-15deg]'>

                    </div>
                </div>
                
          </div>
      </div>


      <div className='col-[1_/_2] row-[3_/_4] max-h-[100px] bg-orange-700
                    '>
        <Footer />
      </div>


        {/* SIDE PANEL */}
      <div className=' bg-green-500 ml-4 col-[2_/_3] row-[2_/_4] border-l-2 border-[#242b2d]'>

      </div>



</div>
```

The footer appears to be below the main body. Did I miss something while declaring the grid-template-rows? I have added bg colors to make it clear.
[This is the current layout. The footer is supposed to be orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTkcA.png)